# Pass parameter to delegate c#

Tags: c#, delegates

I have an issue that I wish to add function calls to a delegate, but each of these function calls will have a unique parameter. I cannot figure it out or find a solution elsewhere so I am turning to you guys :)

Some pseudo below..

(So basically, I am creating a delegate and an event and the AddToDelegate function is supposed to add the function calls to the event (with a unique value), then the GetData function returns all the responses in one string - *the problem comes in the AddToDelegate function as the line `a += new A(SomeFunc)(i.ToString());` should really only be a `+= new A(SomeFunc);`*)

Is there a way to do this with delegates - or am I barking up the wrong tree?

```
public delegate string A(string s);
public event A a;

public void AddToDelegate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DelegateList.Length; i++)
    {
        a += new A(SomeFunc)(i.ToString());
    }
}

public string GetData()
{
    StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (a != null)
    {
        Delegate[] DelegateList = a.GetInvocationList();
        for (int i = 0; i < DelegateList.Length; i++)
        {
            _sb.Append(((A)DelegateList[i]));
        }
    }
    return _sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The pseudo above would produce a string which details all the unique values

Comment: The question asks what you are trying to accomplish, not what the above pseudo-code fails to accomplish. You may indeed be barking up the wrong tree but we can't know it unless you tell us *what* you want to do, rather than *how* you are unable to do it. What are your inputs and what are your expected outputs? Give a usage example, rather than an implementation example.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you really want, but you can use an anonymous function that will hold this extra variable inside its scope:

```
a += new A( s => { 
    string extra_value = i.ToString();
    return SomeFunc(s, extra_value);
  });
```

Which can be simplified into this:

```
a += s => SomeFunc(s, i.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this via [labda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595482/what-are-closures-in-c).

The example below will create add delegates to a that will call SomeFunc with the value of i at the time of the loop.  The variable `capture` is needed to ensure that the correct value is captured - see [How to tell a lambda function to capture a copy instead of a reference in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451779/how-to-tell-a-lambda-function-to-capture-a-copy-instead-of-a-reference-in-c)

```
public event Action<string> a;

public void AddToDelegate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DelegateList.Length; i++)
    {
        int capture = i;
        a += () => SomeFunc(capture.ToString());
    }
}

public string GetData()
{
    StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (a != null)
    {
        Delegate[] DelegateList = a.GetInvocationList();
        for (int i = 0; i < DelegateList.Length; i++)
        {
            _sb.Append((Action<string>)DelegateList[i]());
        }
    }
    return _sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Still need to fix the mess passes to sb.Append().