# runs false if statement when creating new threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing a program that will email Cat Facts to anybody on a mailing list (not spamming, this is more of a learning experience than anything else). I have 2 arrays, 1 for facts (no problems) and one for emails. The one for emails will always throw an exception (even when in a try/catch block) and all of my if statements are completely ignored when this runs.

```
public void Broadcast() {
    fact++;
    if (fact ==factCount) {
        fact = 0;
    }
    String[] mailArray = mailingList.ToArray();
    String[] factArray = factList.ToArray();
    int i = mailArray.Length-1;
    String sendFact = factArray[fact];
    while (i>=0) {
        String s = mailArray[i];
        var t = new Thread(() => Mail(mailArray[i], sendFact));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
        i--;
        if (i==-1) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

The problem is here:

```
var t = new Thread(() => Mail(mailArray[i], sendFact));
```

Even when 'i' is -1, the while statement still runs and the break gets ignored. Originally I ran 'i' in reverse, starting at 0 then counting to mailArray.Length-1. It still gave the same issue, ignoring the while and break when I had them set to run in reverse.

Is this a problem with creating new threads?

Edit:

I moved:

```
    var t = new Thread(() => Mail(mailArray[i], sendFact));
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
```

To a new method and called that instead of the code above - that works perfectly fine.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: The lambda captures the `i` *variable*, not *value*. So by the time the threads start, `i` is `-1`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451779/how-to-tell-a-lambda-function-to-capture-a-copy-instead-of-a-reference-in-c

Comment: General advice: Use a foreach loop and don't use threads as a beginner (very hard to get right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a closure over the loop variable - this is a [well known problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Using `s` directly, as you already have assigned to it the current value, would fix it:

```
while (i>=0)
{
  string s = mailArray[i];
  var t = new Thread(() => Mail(s, sendFact));
  //..
}
```

Comment: Yep, that works. I tried to make the string s to see if it would throw an exception, I didn't think of just using s to start the thread.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this a problem with creating new threads?

Sort of. It's a problem with capturing `i` in a lambda expression, and then changing it. It means that when the thread executes your lambda expression, it takes the *current* value of `i`, not the value of `i` in the loop iteration that you created the thread in.

The simplest solution is to declare a new local variable *inside* the loop, copy `i` into that, and then use that variable in the lambda expression:

```
while (i >= 0)
{
    var copy = i;
    String s = mailArray[i];
    var t = new Thread(() => Mail(mailArray[copy], sendFact));
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
    i--;
}
```

Or just use `s`, which you've already initialized *outside* the lambda expression:

```
while (i >= 0)
{
    String s = mailArray[i];
    var t = new Thread(() => Mail(s, sendFact));
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
    i--;
}
```

Or, rather more readably, IMO, just use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var item in mailArray)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => Mail(item, sendFact)) { IsBackground = true };
    t.Start();
}
```

This will have the same problem under C# 3 and 4, but under C# 5 the behaviour of capturing the iterator variable in a `foreach` loop was fixed.

(You should consider using `Task` instead of `Thread`, and potentially using something like `Parallel.ForEach` instead, btw.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, and it's related to the creation of this lambda expression:

```
() => Mail(mailArray[i], sendFact)
```

Basically, you're telling the thread class to start a new thread, and when it does, to execute that code.

Unfortunately, it will not make a snapshot of what the value of `i` is at that time, so let's say that due to timing, before the thread actually starts, you manage to increase `i`. The thread will call that lambda, using the current value of `i`, not the value `i` had when you created the lambda.

This is easy to fix, however.

Inside the while-loop, add a temporary variable to capture the current value of `i`, and use that variable in your lambda expression:

```
int temp = i;
var t = new Thread(() => Mail(mailArray(temp), sendFact));
```

For more information, check out the following link: [C# in Depth: The Beauty of Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx).