# How is a c# lambda capturing variables

Tags: c#, lambda, closures

Why does the following code print 11 twice?

```
int i = 10;
Action fn1 = () => Console.WriteLine(i);
i = 11;
Action fn2 = () => Console.WriteLine(i);
fn1();
fn2();
```

Output
11
11

According to the answers in this post - [How to tell a lambda function to capture a copy instead of a reference in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451779/how-to-tell-a-lambda-function-to-capture-a-copy-instead-of-a-reference-in-c) - a lambda is translated into a class with a copy of the captured variable. If that is the case shouldn't my example have printed 10 & 11?

Now, when a lambda captures by reference how does it affect the life time of the variable captured. For instance, assume that the above piece of code was in a function & the Actions' scope was global to the variable like this:

```
class Test
{
  Action _fn1;
  Action _fn2;

  void setActions()
  {
    int i = 10;
    _fn1 = () => Console.WriteLine(i);
    i = 11;
    _fn2 = () => Console.WriteLine(i);
  }

  static void Main()
  {
    setActions();
    _fn1();
    _fn2();
  }
}
```

In this scenario wouldn't the variable i have gone out of scope when the actions are invoked? So, are the actions left with a dangling pointer sort of reference?

Answer (score 10):

> If that is the case shouldn't my example have printed 10 & 11?

No, because you've only got a single variable - `fn1` captures the *variable*, not its current *value*. So a method like this:

```
static void Foo()
{
    int i = 10;
    Action fn1 = () => Console.WriteLine(i);
    i = 11;
    Action fn2 = () => Console.WriteLine(i);
    fn1();
    fn2(); 
}
```

is translated like this:

```
class Test
{
    class MainVariableHolder
    {
        public int i;
        public void fn1() => Console.WriteLine(i);
        public void fn2() => Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    void Foo()
    {
        var holder = new MainVariableHolder();
        holder.i = 10;
        Action fn1 = holder.fn1;
        holder.i = 11;
        Action fn2 = holder.fn2;
        fn1();
        fn2();
    }
}
```

This answers your second point too: the variable is "hoisted" into a class, so its lifetime is effectively extended as long as the delegate is alive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, why would the two lambdas be represented by a single class? I thought they would each have a separate class. Could you point me to an evidence to this? I attempted looking at the IL code via ILSpy but it doesn't show the classes generated for the lambda.

Comment: @Sumith: It couldn't use two classes, as then you'd end up with two variables - if `fn1` modifies `i`, that needs to be visible in `fn2`. As for how you verify it: use ildasm instead of ilspy, or (if you can) disable "optimizations" in ilspy (so that it does less work to reconstruct the original C#)

Comment: @Sumith: If you go into View / Options and untick "Decompile lambdas" etc, you'll see code like I've shown.

Comment: Would this be an example of closures as also described in this [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)

Comment: @Scrobi: Yes, it is.

Comment: I wish it worked more like the C++ lambdas where you can clearly specify whether to capture by value or capture by reference. (By the by I am just yet to read "The Beauty of Closures" shared by @Scrobi)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a class is generated that has as it's fields the captured variables, not their values. So, when the lamba would be executed the runtime would check for the *current* value of `i`, which is 11, since you have updated this, before you call the lambda. This is why you see this. In order to validate this argument, you could rearrange the ordering of your statements as below:

```
int i = 10;
Action fn1 = () => Console.WriteLine(i);
fn1();
i = 11;
Action fn2 = () => Console.WriteLine(i);
fn2();
```

Answer (score -1):

It prints twice because of deferred execution, not because of the way it captures variables.

When the execution is deferred, it will print the latest value of i, since i is what is captured, not it's value.

Comment: " since i is what is captured, not it's value." - in other way, it *is* because of the way it captures variables. (The point is it captures the variable, not the value)