Do C# lambda functions create memory allocations?
I would like to make some heap allocation free methods for performing some operations. Some of these methods accept a delegate as their parameters. My concern is about what if passing in a lambda function to these methods would cause heap allocations. For example, consider the following code:
public SomeItem FindItem(Predicate<SomeItem> predicate)
{
    // Return something by calling predicate(someItem) multiple times.
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    var myItem = FindItem(item => item.IsValid);

    // Do something.
}

Considering the code sample above, would a call to DoSomething() cause any heap allocation, in the current version of C# and .NET?
And what about alternatives? Are there types of delegates or conventions for lambda functions in .NET that are heap allocation free? I've read about a ValueAction<T> proposal, somewhere around .NET Core 2.1, but I don't know if it was actually implemented, or if something like it already exists in .NET 8.

No, it does not allocate memory - it's just another (more convenient/flexible) way to pass in a function pointer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496018/how-is-a-c-sharp-lambda-capturing-variables
