# How to prevent "index" to updated itself in array of Action

Tags: c#, delegates, action

When I add to `array` of `Actions` with a  `for loop` a `delegate` the I is updated across the array. How to prevent that from happening?

I have tried assigning the "I" to an integer before adding that works.

```
Action[] actions = new Action[100];

for (int i = 0;i< actions.Length; i++)
{
    actions[i] = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello"+ i);
}
```

"I" in each Action in `Action[]` is 100;

Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell a lambda function to capture a copy instead of a reference in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451779/how-to-tell-a-lambda-function-to-capture-a-copy-instead-of-a-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451779/how-to-tell-a-lambda-function-to-capture-a-copy-instead-of-a-reference-in-c) and  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp) are good explanations on similar question. [Here](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Closures) is also good explanation on C# closures by Jon Skeet.

In `for` loop there is only one single variable `i` used. That's why later on when you are executing actions, they all reference to same value `i=100`. If action need to use actual value of the current `i` you have to capture a copy of it and store copy to action.

```
for (int i = 0;i< actions.Length; i++)
{   
    int copy = i;
    actions[i] = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello"+ copy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because they are all assigned to the same local variable "int i"
and after the loop end "i" is 100

```
Action[] actions = new Action[100];

for (int i = 0;i< actions.Length; i++)
{
    int a = i;
    actions[i] = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello"+ a);
}
```

after declare int a = i , you have respective a for each actions