# Button.onClick.AddListener(() => ItemButton(i)) Applies the same i value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

So, I worked on my shop system and I wanted to make it so that when the player presses the button, that button was selected (**I need to know the id of button that I press**)

```
void Awake()
{
    //Cycle through all the ShopItems
    for (int i = 0; i < shopItemsList.Count; i++)
    {
        go = Instantiate(ItemTemplate, ShopScrollView);
        go.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => ItemButton(i));
        go.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = shopItemsList[i].itemName;

        if (!shopItemsList[i].isPurchased)
        {
            go.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (shopItemsList[i].isChosen)
        {
            go.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(164, 0, 0, 255);
        }
            go.transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().txt = shopItemsList[i].price.ToString() + "$";
        }
    }


    void ItemButton(int itemName)
    {
        Debug.Log(itemName);
    }
}
```

So when I Press Play button in Unity all works fine (every item has its stats) but **all buttons have the same value that equals to 12 (the last iteration of "for" cycle)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how captures and `for` loops works in C# (you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/451849/2501279) or [here](https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/) for example). Introduce temporary variable, assign `i` to it and use it in lambda:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < shopItemsList.Count; i++)
    {
        var temp = i;
        go = Instantiate(ItemTemplate, ShopScrollView);
        go.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => ItemButton(temp));
        ....
    }
```

Comment: If this was answered before shouldn't we mark it as duplicate instead of answering again? ;)