# Tasks fail to launch properly

Tags: c#, task

```cs
private static int[] Sort(int[] arr)
        {
            int temp;
            int[] result = new int[arr.Length];
            Array.Copy(arr, result, arr.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length - 1; i++)
            {

                for (int j = i + 1; j < result.Length; j++)
                {

                    if (result[i] > result[j])
                    {
                        temp = result[i];
                        result[i] = result[j];
                        result[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

public static List<List<T>> ChunkBy<T>(this List<T> source, int chunkSize)
        {
            return source
                .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
                .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
                .ToList();
        }
...
List<List<int>> unsortedLists = list.ChunkBy(chunkSize);
            int count = unsortedLists.Count;
            List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();

            Task<List<int>>[] tasks = new Task<List<int>>[count];
            //from 0 to 9
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                tasks[i] = new Task<List<int>>(() =>
                {
                    lists[i] = Sort(unsortedLists[i].ToArray()).ToList(); //out of range exception i = 10
                    return lists[i];
                });          
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                tasks[i].Start();
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                lists[i] = await tasks[i]; //array out of range
            }
```

I'm facing extremely weird error. I have slightly simplified my code and provided the important part.

I'm creating a bunch of tasks, starting them, and then it fails instantly at 3rd loop. For some reason it uses old iterator that ended on 9, and increases it to 10, creating exception. I have no idea what to do, at the moment it looks like error of the environment.

Comment: The value of count should be int count = unsortedLists.Count().

Comment: @jdweng it is equal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell a lambda function to capture a copy instead of a reference in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451779/how-to-tell-a-lambda-function-to-capture-a-copy-instead-of-a-reference-in-c)

Comment: You need to capture the loop variable. Alternatively `tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(i => Task.Run(() => {......}).ToArray(); await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: @juharr above where you can't see it. I'm pretty sure i just don't know how to create tasks in a loop.

Comment: Please update the code extract to be [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [never use the task constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html). In this case, use `Task.Run` instead.

Your other problem is that the `for` loop in C# only defines a single loop variable, and lambdas close over *variables*, not *values*. This is why you're seeing an `i` that is `10`.

The simplest solution is to do away with the `for` loops completely:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, count)
    .Select(i => Task.Run(() =>
    {
      lists[i] = Sort(unsortedLists[i].ToArray()).ToList();
      return lists[i];
    }))
    .ToList();
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```